# HTML Table Spacing weirdness in Outlook 2010 and 2007

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I'm coding a HTML email newsletter and I'm getting very weird spacing issues for my tables in Outlook 2007 and 2010

My code which works fine in all other clients is here:

```
<table width="575" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0054a4" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
            <a href="http://www.lgfhfghfhfhfghf" target="_blank" style="font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana, Georgia; font-size:30px; line-height: 34px; font-style:normal; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">
                <center>
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;">register</span> for <span style="font-style:lighter;color:#fce000;">mkk</span><span style="color:#fce000; font-weight:bold;"> 56565464646 </span><span style="font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;">click here</span></strong>
                </center>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#fce000" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:15px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><a href="http://www.fgdfgdg" target="_blank" style="font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana, Georgia; font-size:30px; line-height: 30px; font-style:normal; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">
                <center>
                    <span style="font-style:lighter;color:#0054a4;">lll</span><span style="color:#0054a4; font-weight:bold;"> ffgfgf </span><span style="font-weight:normal; color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">is proudly sponsored by</span></strong>
                </center>
            </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0054a4" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
            <a href="http://www.gdfgdfgdf" target="_blank"><img name="fgdgfg" src="http://fgfdgdgdg" width="575" height="76" style="font-size:20px; color:#fce000;" alt="fgfdgdfgdfg" border="0"/></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#0055a5" align="center" width="575" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" bgcolor="#0055a5" valign="top">
            <img src="http://www.fdgfdgdfgdfgdf.png" height="50" width="50" alt="gggggg" align="top" border="no" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;" />
        </td>
        <td align="right" bgcolor="#0055a5" valign="top" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:30px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;color:#fce000;" >
            <span style="font-weight:bold;color:##fce000;" >gfrtryrtytryrtyrty</span><br />
            rtrtrtrtertretertetertertertertertertertetert <font style="text-decoration:none;">tertetertetetet</font> <a href=mailto:fgdfgdfgdgdfgfdstyle="color:#fce000; text-decoration:none;" >rtdfgdfgdfgdfg</a> / <a href="http://www.fgdfgdfgdgdgdf" target="_blank" style="color:#fce000;text-decoration:none;">www.fgfgdfgfgd/expo</a><br />
            <strong> To unsubscribe from this newsletter </strong><a href="http://$UNSUB$" style="color:#fce000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline" >click here</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Screenshot of the weirdness:
[image: weirdness]

Screenshot of working email:

[image: working]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

They have a pdf that contains what works in mailclients, css, html and more.

Comment: Ummm that doesnt really help me sorry.  I really need to know whats causing the spacing and how to solve it :D

Comment: If you change padding to margin, will it work better then? I can't really test, since I don't have outlook 2007 or 2010 :/

Comment: Hm.. If you set line-height: 0px; on the TD, does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful list of quirks in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 in how it displays HTML emails: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/tips_and_tricks_outlook_07-13#outlook07-13_tip16

The page includes this tip, which fits with the way you've coded the table:

> Avoid using “margin” or “padding” CSS properties in your TABLE tag.
>   Cellpadding and Cellspacing attributes are generally safe but margin
>   or padding will often be added to every TD within the table.

Hope that helps get to the bottom of it.